# Private Key Storage in Metamask Chrome

Tags: metamask, private

I recently treated myself to a fresh install of Ubuntu, however did not separately back up my keys from metamask. I still have the old `.config/google-chrome` folder however from my home directory. I've read that metamask stores keys in encrypted format in this local storage folder (old metamask version, not `local.storage`), however after some poking around in the `.ldb` files I cannot seem to find anything resembling the encrypted keys.

I recall my password but not my seed words. Can I manually retrieve my encrypted key so I can use my password to decrypt?

Comment: See this answer if it helps you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52658/where-does-metamask-store-the-wallet-seed-file-path. Also check Metamask documentation https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015289852-How-to-Copy-Your-Vault-Data.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you find JSON formated text file with keys such as "id", "cipher", "ciphertext", "salt"...etc, I don't think you would be able to recover. If you find it, you will be able to extract it via not just metamask but also other tools, assuming you know the correct password. You need either that or your mnemonic. Password is just missing information to extract your keys from the file I mentioned. Dig deeper through that folders, hope you find it :)

Comment: Yep. Grep doesn't turn up anything. So it doesn't seem to be stored as a regular JSON keyfile.

Comment: Hmm...I was hoping that it uses regular format such as commonly used ethereum nodes, since it provides import option that can read this kind of files.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real old post, but if you haven't figured it out and still have the files: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018766351-How-to-recover-your-Secret-Recovery-Phrase

I'm in a similar, but more hopeless situation.  Following this, however, did allow me to find the mnemonic for other accounts (which I'd already backed up), but didn't find the imported account I'm trying to recover.

Good luck!

Mark