# How to recover/find metamask wallet file

Tags: wallets, metamask, recovery

So I had foolishly kept my metamask passphrase only on StickyNotes. This meant when my computer crashed, I had to reinstall all my programs, but all my files remained. For some reason my stickynotes program updated and my previous stickynotes disappeared from the program. I had an older version of the notes but these did not contain the pass phrase.

My question is where I should look for the metamask file? Since my browsers were reinstalled, I cant find any metamask related files under chrome extensions in the appdata/local folders. 
I followed the advice here:[Where does metamask store the wallet seed? (file path)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52658/where-does-metamask-store-the-wallet-seed-file-path?rq=1)
But my 0003 file was almost empty due to the reinstallation of chrome and the removal of any extensions I had.

Is there anything else I can try? Either to recover the stickynotes files somehow or find a metamask file? I have the password but dont know where to look for a pass phrase.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot, but you can try to run a data recovery program like [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva). Hard drives don't instantly delete data after it has been deleted from the file system, instead they mark the space as available and overwrite it when necessary. Recuva may be able to recover those files.